# Java exception factory for higher level exceptions

Tags: java

I am looking to create a exception factory

I have a service that connects to different data stores and these data stores throw a number of exceptions. 
I do not want to return these exceptions to users of the service but instead return higher level exception
e.g. storeServiceTransientReadException

When connecting to the data store I will use a try, catch throw pattern; e.g for a Cassandra connection:

```
public ResultSet safeExecute(Statement statement) throws StoreServiceException {
    try {
        return session.execute(statement);
    } 
    catch(QueryExecutionException ex){
        log.error(ex);
        StoreServiceException storeException = StoreServiceExceptionFactory.getTransientException(ex);
        throw storeException;
    }
```

In the cassandra example I want the factory to create a read or write storeServiceException  exception depending on whether the exception is a ReadFailureException, ReadTimeoutException, WriteFailureException or  WriteTimeoutException

For other data stores I want to follow the same pattern then users of the service will only have to worry about the service errors and not specific data store errors.

For the factory I was think something along the lines of (in pseudo):

```
public class ExceptionsFactory {

public StoreServiceTransientException getTransientException(Exception ex){

    if  ReadException
        return  StoreServiceTransientException("read exception ")


    if WriteException 
        return  StoreServiceTransientException("write exception ")

}

public StoreServiceNonTransientException getTransientNonException(Exception ex){

    if  ReadException
        return  StoreServiceNonTransientException("read exception ")


    if WriteException 
        return  StoreServiceNonTransientException("write exception ")


}
```

But I cannot  find many online example of this which worries me. 
It is a really bad idea?
I should just have lots more specific catch blocks that return the storeServiceException I want?

Comment: It's common practice in Java for class names to begin with uppercase letters. `StoreServiceTransientException` would be a quick, yet huge improvement

Comment: @byxor good point -- typo on my part when I tried to make the example more generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is a really bad idea?* In my opinion, yes. This is a bad idea. The expensive part of using `Exception`(s) is filling in the stack trace. If you pre-create and save the `Exception` you throw then the stack trace will be meaningless (or at least of greatly reduced value). You aren't currently logging stack traces, so I would also change

```
log.error(ex);
```

to

```
log.error("Caught exception: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
```

And similarly instantiate exceptions with the underlying cause -

```
throw new storeServiceException("Exception in storage.", ex);
```

And the name should follow normal naming conventions. Java class names start with a capital letter - yours' looks like a variable.

Comment: my bad -  update the example and removed the typo.  Thanks for the info!